# Liferay 6.2: Allow public access to one JSON API method

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to provide public access to the URL `http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/journalarticle/get-article-by-url-title/group-id/10182/url-title/events`

When I try accessing this URL without being logged in to Liferay, I get the following error:

```
{"exception":"Authenticated access required"}
```

I've tried setting the following in portal-ext.properties:

```
json.service.public.methods=*
jsonws.web.service.public.methods=*
```

I've also tried setting the values to `get*` with no luck. I need to access this API through an AngularJs application that is hosted on a different domain, so I also need to set up CORS access if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I have tried all the above non have worked, What you can do is in your custom portlet create your own API for JSON web services in that call the API

```
JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticleByUrlTitle(groupId, urlTitle);
```

In your *ServiceImp.java add the tag below, see the example

> @AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled=true)

Example:

```
@AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled=true)
public JurnalArtical yourMethodName(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding properties in portal-ext.properties

```
json.web.service.enabled=true
json.service.auth.token.enabled=false
auth.token.check.enabled=false
json.service.auth.token.hosts.allowed=
```

leave the fourth one empty.

This will disable the authentication needed for JSON call for Liferay.

Comment: Still get the same exception even after adding the 3rd property. I've tried restarting the server. BTW, I'm using the enterprise version of Liferay if that makes any difference.

Comment: I guess, no difference, if you use EE or CE. I've updated with another property.

Comment: Nope. I'm trying the same config for a CE version to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you find any success for this. Plz update the Answer.